# intellicode for javascript (React) not working on VS Code windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellicode

vscode's code hinting function doesn't work with javascript even though other languages (C, C ++, python ,, ...) still work.
I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> but it still doesn't work

[intellicode with javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6gRD.png)

[intellicode with css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ9ZK.png)

Comment: Have you tried saving the file to a `.js` format?

Comment: @ZenBoat Yes, I am making an app initialized by create-react-app. Everything was fine but yesterday it got an error, even though I didn't update or install the extension for vscode